# How to dynamically modify the front-end of an app using Shopify without editing template files?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I've created a Shopify app that performs back-end operations like selecting products, modifying images, and storing data in the app's database. Now, I want to display this modified data on the front-end of the product page without making any changes to the template files.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Back-end operations work as expected.
- Data is being stored in the app's database.

I'm looking for guidance on how to retrieve this data from the database and dynamically update the front-end of the product page. I want to achieve this without directly editing the Shopify theme templates to ensure compatibility and maintainability.

Any suggestions or examples on how to achieve this in Shopify using app development best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Context:

- The Shopify app is developed using React Remix and Prisma.
- Database is set up and data is being stored successfully.
- I want to avoid editing Shopify theme template files directly to ensure compatibility with various themes.

Comment: You can achieve something like this using [Theme App Extensions](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions)

Comment: I am also stuck on same, I created prisma database then i want to show my blog how i can do this?